# Hello World with Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I´m trying to create a hello world with spring on eclipse. But i get the next error:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource  
[src/com/spr/main/contextApplication.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [src/com/spr/main/contextApplication.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/com/spr/main/contextApplication.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
at com.spr.main.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/com/spr/main/contextApplication.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
... 4 more
```

I have tried :

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("\\src\\com\\spr\\main\\contextApplication.xml"));
```

and

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("\\src\\com\\spr\\main\\contextApplication.xml"));
```

and the contextApplication.xml path is src/com/spr/main/

Comment: what's the code that's giving the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your declaration from

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("\\src\\com\\spr\\main\\contextApplication.xml"));
```

to

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("com\\spr\\main\\contextApplication.xml"));
```

dont forget to check filename.

Comment: great congrats go for acceptance.

Comment: He means "Accept this answer" - it is customary, on StackOverflow, to mark as "accepted" the answer that satisfies your question.  Doing so elevates the reputation of the person who took their time to answer, and if you don't do it regularly, people stop answering your questions.